# How do I give Permission to a Group to just one Library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have certain Libraries in SP 2013 site.
Say example:
A,
B,
C,
D

What if I want a set of Users say SharePoint Group 'X' to have permission only on Library 'B' and nothing other than that.

How can I achieve this.?

Comment: You mean programmatically? Which programming language/library do you use? (In case not, this question is off-topic on SO. Maybe you can have more success on serverfault.)

Comment: I need to implement this using Out Of the Box Features.

Comment: I tried with the following:
1. Break the permission of Library 'B'
2. Gave permission to a particular user to this library

But when the user tries to access the same library, its giving access denied error.

Comment: @KevinVora _Gave permission to a particular user_ Witch permission ?

Comment: The user 'U' do not have any access to the site.
Gave Read Permission to a user 'U' in the Library 'B' after breaking the permission inheritance.

Comment: Usually this appears to work fine for the other site. But this is a dedicated Sharepoint Online Site.
Its a Host named site collection office 365.
Would this make a difference.?